# Is there a preferred Python gui to use

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm attempting to convert a Python application I coded using the cmd module into a gui. Initially, I came across EasyGui. But after giving it a try, I find that it is very limited, the gui screens are not consistent, and overall not easy on the eyes. I read about IronPython (Python + .NET), but cannot find adequate documentation on it. Before I order a book from Amazon on IronPython (as this seems the most legitimate), does anyone know of a decent gui alternative for Python? Thanks!

Comment: Preferred is quite subjective. You might like wxPython, it's powerful and very easy to use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development might help.

Comment: You may find some useful information in this related question: [What cross-platform GUI libraries are simple, lightweight, and have minimal dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426718/what-cross-platform-gui-libraries-are-simple-lightweight-and-have-minimal-depen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tkinter is in the standard library, works on all platforms, and is fairly simple and lightweight, but it looks a bit clunky.

WxPython tries to use platform widgets, so it looks a bit better, but it's a separate library. On Linux, I still find it doesn't look quite right.

PyQt is a large, powerful framework - it looks good, and you can do a lot with it, but it's more complex and a larger install.

There are plenty of others, but those are probably the most popular.

Comment: It's not worth me writing a separate answer just to add these remarks... but it's worth noting that PySide is most likely the future of QT bindings rather PyQT (due to more flexible licensing).  Also, both Wx and Qt have arguably more active communities and better documentation.  Finally, due to Nokia's investments, PySide/Qt has the most complete and up-to-date free WYSIWYG builder available (if that's important to you).

Comment: I've used all three over the past decade (particularly Tk and Wx), but have come to really enjoy Qt recently.  I think it gets overlooked because it used to have tighter licensing restrictions, and many people might not be aware that it changed to the same license as GTK awhile back.

Comment: @steve Since Nokia recently sold off Qt I'm guessing PySide is going to die off http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/03/07/1337211/Nokia-Sells-Qt?from=rss

Comment: @jhocking: Despite /. senasationalism, Nokia has *not* sold Qt. They sold the right to sell commercial licenses, but retained the codebase. Whether they'll still put in as much effort on development, I don't know. But it's been nearly 4 months since that story, their Qt website is still updated, and pyside is still getting commits. So I wouldn't call it dead just yet.

Comment: Exactly.  Qt is a great framework, but its public perception for some reason is totally snakebit (pardon the Python pun!).  Most of the "problems" people talk about are based on outdated or misleading information:  [1] licensing issues (resolved years ago), [2] native look-n-feel (available for years now), and [3] questionable long-term investment from Nokia (as opposed to Tk and Wx, which never received any investment in the first place).

Comment: Well that distinction is nice to know. I used PySide before when I did a GUI app in Python, so that'll be a nice option to still have available next time I need to do a GUI app in Python.

Comment: @jhocking: For now, the public APIs are very similar. For an IPython frontend, we've got a module which will import PyQt or Pyside depending as necessary: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/external/qt.py

Answer (score 1):

I've used [libglade](http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/libglade/) before to write GUIs in Python. I thought the results felt very native (as native as any GUI toolkit can under Linux), and using it was a lot like every other GUI toolkit I've used.

Answer (score 0):

The best GUI's for Python are tkinter, Qt (PyQt), and wx (wxPython). Search any of those terms to learn more.